# Using Tensorflow to detect falls and implementing the model in Android

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset

It's my first post on the forum, so please excuse any major errors or stupidities on my part.

I'm currently doing a project on fall detection using machine learning. I've seen many examples online about ADL's (Activites of Daily Live) and Tensorflow and tried to use some of them as a basis to my work. For example, this one: https://medium.com/@curiousily/human-activity-recognition-using-lstms-on-android-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-vi-492da5adef64.

What I did was use the known WISDM dataset (this one: http://www.cis.fordham.edu/wisdm/dataset.php) as the "Not Falling" examples and found another dataset with 30 fall examples (this one: http://fenix.univ.rzeszow.pl/~mkepski/ds/uf.html).

However, I'm encountering some problems regarding the use of the model on the smartphone. Even tough I see, in some cases, accuracy levels of 80-90% and up, when I test the model on an App, the results are **horrible**. Is it even possible to do it this way? What could be the problem?

I've tried numerous ways to mix the datasets, changing the learn rate, the complexity of the model, etc. but still no luck...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
from pylab import rcParams
from pylab import plot
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

sns.set(style='whitegrid', palette='muted', font_scale=1.5)

rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 14, 8

RANDOM_SEED = 42
columns = ['user','activity','timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
df_train = pd.read_csv('test_4.txt', header = None, names = columns)
df_test = pd.read_csv('train_4.txt', header = None, names = columns)
print('Data read.')
df_train['activity'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Training examples by activity type');
#df['user'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Training examples by user');
plt.show()
df_test['activity'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Training examples by activity type');
#df['user'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='Training examples by user');
plt.show()

##def plot_activity(activity, df):
##    data = df[df['activity'] == activity][['x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']][:200]
##    axis = data.plot(subplots=True, figsize=(16, 12), 
##                     title=activity)
##    for ax in axis:
##        ax.legend(loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))
##plot_activity("Jogging", df)
##plt.show()

## TRAIN DATA - EACH GENERATED SEQUENCE MUST CONTAIN 200 TRAINING EXAMPLES
N_TIME_STEPS = 200
N_FEATURES = 3
step = 1
segments = []
labels = []
for i in range(0, len(df_train) - N_TIME_STEPS, step):
    xs = df_train['x-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    ys = df_train['y-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    zs = df_train['z-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    label = stats.mode(df_train['activity'][i: i + N_TIME_STEPS])[0][0]
    segments.append([xs, ys, zs])
    labels.append(label)
    print(i)

print('Train sequences generated.')    
np.array(segments).shape
reshaped_segments = np.asarray(segments, dtype= np.float32).reshape(-1, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES)
labels = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels), dtype = np.float32)
X_train = reshaped_segments
y_train = labels
print(X_train)

## TEST DATA - EACH GENERATED SEQUENCE MUST CONTAIN 200 TRAINING EXAMPLES
N_TIME_STEPS = 200
N_FEATURES = 3
step = 1
segments = []
labels = []
for i in range(0, len(df_test) - N_TIME_STEPS, step):
    xs = df_test['x-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    ys = df_test['y-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    zs = df_test['z-axis'].values[i: i + N_TIME_STEPS]
    label = stats.mode(df_test['activity'][i: i + N_TIME_STEPS])[0][0]
    segments.append([xs, ys, zs])
    labels.append(label)
    print(i)

print('Test sequences generated.')    
np.array(segments).shape
reshaped_segments = np.asarray(segments, dtype= np.float32).reshape(-1, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES)
labels = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(labels), dtype = np.float32)
X_test = reshaped_segments
y_test = labels


## SPLITING THE DATA INTO TRAINING AND TEST (20%) SET
##X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(reshaped_segments, labels, test_size=0.5, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)



##train_size = int(0.7 * segments)
##test_size = int(0.3 * segments)
##
##full_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FLAGS.input_file)
##full_dataset = full_dataset.shuffle()
##train_dataset = full_dataset.take(train_size)
##test_dataset = full_dataset.skip(train_size)
##test_dataset = test_dataset.take(test_size)


## THE LSTM MODEL DEFINITION
N_CLASSES = 2
N_HIDDEN_UNITS = 64
def create_LSTM_model(inputs):
    W = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_FEATURES, N_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS, N_CLASSES]))
    }
    biases = {
        'hidden': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_HIDDEN_UNITS], mean=1.0)),
        'output': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([N_CLASSES]))
    }

    X = tf.transpose(inputs, [1, 0, 2])
    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, N_FEATURES])
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X, W['hidden']) + biases['hidden'])
    hidden = tf.split(hidden, N_TIME_STEPS, 0)

    # Stack 2 LSTM layers
    lstm_layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(N_HIDDEN_UNITS, forget_bias=1.0) for _ in range(2)]
    lstm_layers = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layers)

    outputs, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_layers, hidden, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Get output for the last time step
    lstm_last_output = outputs[-1]

    return tf.matmul(lstm_last_output, W['output']) + biases['output']
print('LSTM model defined.')

## CREATE PLACEHOLDERS FOR THE MODEL
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_TIME_STEPS, N_FEATURES], name="input")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N_CLASSES])
print('LSTM model placeholders defined.')

## CREATING THE MODEL
pred_Y = create_LSTM_model(X)
pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(pred_Y, name="y_")
print('LSTM model created.')


## USE OF L2 REGULARIZATION
L2_LOSS = 0.0015
l2 = L2_LOSS * \
    sum(tf.nn.l2_loss(tf_var) for tf_var in tf.trainable_variables())
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = pred_Y, labels = Y))


## OPTIMIZER
LEARNING_RATE = 5e-5
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE).minimize(loss)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred_softmax, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, dtype=tf.float32))


# TRAINING
N_EPOCHS = 5
BATCH_SIZE = 1024
##batch_size = 10
##total_batchs = X_train.shape[0] ## batch_size

saver = tf.train.Saver()

history = dict(train_loss=[], 
                     train_acc=[], 
                     test_loss=[], 
                     test_acc=[])

sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

train_count = len(X_train)

for i in range(1, N_EPOCHS + 1):
    for start, end in zip(range(0, train_count, BATCH_SIZE),
                          range(BATCH_SIZE, train_count + 1,BATCH_SIZE)):

        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: X_train[start:end],
                                       Y: y_train[start:end]})

    _, acc_train, loss_train = sess.run([pred_softmax, accuracy, loss], feed_dict={
                                            X: X_train, Y: y_train})

    _, acc_test, loss_test = sess.run([pred_softmax, accuracy, loss], feed_dict={
                                            X: X_test, Y: y_test})

    history['train_loss'].append(loss_train)
    history['train_acc'].append(acc_train)
    history['test_loss'].append(loss_test)
    history['test_acc'].append(acc_test)

    print ("epoch: %d test accuracy: %f loss: %f" %(i,acc_test,loss_test))

##history = dict(train_loss=[], 
##                     train_acc=[], 
##                     test_loss=[], 
##                     test_acc=[])
##saver = tf.train.Saver()
##session = tf.Session()
##tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=session)
##for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
##    cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1],dtype=float)
##    for b in range(total_batchs):
##        offset = (b * batch_size) % (y_train.shape[0] - batch_size)
##        batch_x = X_train[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
##        batch_y = y_train[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
##        _, c = session.run([optimizer, loss],feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y : batch_y})
##        cost_history = np.append(cost_history,c)
##    print ("Epoch: %d Training Loss: %f Training Accuracy %f" %(epoch,np.mean(cost_history),session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: y_train})))
##print ("Testing Accuracy: %f" %(session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={X: X_test, Y: y_test})))



predictions, acc_final, loss_final = sess.run([pred_softmax, accuracy, loss], feed_dict={X: X_test, Y: y_test})

print()
print ("final results: accuracy: %f loss: %f" %(acc_final,loss_final))


## STORE MODEL TO DISK
pickle.dump(predictions, open("predictions.p", "wb"))
pickle.dump(history, open("history.p", "wb"))
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', './checkpoint/har.pbtxt')  
saver.save(sess, save_path = "./checkpoint/har.ckpt")
sess.close()


## LOADING THE MODEL
history = pickle.load(open("history.p", "rb"))
predictions = pickle.load(open("predictions.p", "rb"))


# MODEL EVALUATION
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(np.array(history['train_loss']), "r--", label="Train loss")
plt.plot(np.array(history['train_acc']), "g--", label="Train accuracy")
plt.plot(np.array(history['test_loss']), "r-", label="Test loss")
plt.plot(np.array(history['test_acc']), "g-", label="Test accuracy")
plt.title("Training session's progress over iterations")
plt.legend(loc='upper right', shadow=True)
plt.ylabel('Training Progress (Loss or Accuracy values)')
plt.xlabel('Training Epoch')
plt.ylim(0)
plt.show()


# CONFUSION MATRIX
LABELS = ["Falling", "NotFalling"];
##LABELS = ["Downstairs", "Falling", "Jogging", "Sitting", "Standing", "Upstairs", "Walking"];
max_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
max_predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
confusion_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(max_test, max_predictions)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix, xticklabels=LABELS, yticklabels=LABELS, annot=True, fmt="d");
plt.title("Confusion matrix")
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.show();
```

Here is the code I used to export the model:

```
from tensorflow.python.tools import freeze_graph

MODEL_NAME = 'har'

input_graph_path = 'checkpoint/' + MODEL_NAME+'.pbtxt'
checkpoint_path = './checkpoint/' +MODEL_NAME+'.ckpt'
restore_op_name = "save/restore_all"
filename_tensor_name = "save/Const:0"
output_frozen_graph_name = 'frozen_'+MODEL_NAME+'.pb'

freeze_graph.freeze_graph(input_graph_path, input_saver="",
                          input_binary=False, input_checkpoint=checkpoint_path, 
                          output_node_names="y_", restore_op_name="save/restore_all",
                          filename_tensor_name="save/Const:0", 
                          output_graph=output_frozen_graph_name, clear_devices=True, initializer_nodes="")
```

And this is the code I used on the Android App:

```
package com.example.daniel.app03;

import android.content.Context;

import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;


public class TensorFlowClassifier {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("tensorflow_inference");
    }

    private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
    private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/frozen_har.pb";
    private static final String INPUT_NODE = "input";
    private static final String[] OUTPUT_NODES = {"y_"};
    private static final String OUTPUT_NODE = "y_";
    private static final long[] INPUT_SIZE = {1, 200, 3};
    private static final int OUTPUT_SIZE = 2;

    public TensorFlowClassifier(final Context context) {
        inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(context.getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);
    }

    public float[] predictProbabilities(float[] data) {
        float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, data, INPUT_SIZE);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, result);

        //Downstairs    Falling     Jogging   Sitting   Standing    Upstairs    Walking
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here are the loss and the accuracy graphs. Using all 7 classes:

[image: Loss and accuracy evolution with 7 classes]

[image: Confusion matrix with 7 classes]

With just 2 classes ("Falling" and "NotFalling"):

[image: Loss and accuracy evolution with 2 classes]

[image: Confusion matrix with 2 classes]

**Note: In this case I tried to use less ADL examples ("NotFalling") so there is less of a discrepancy.**

Comment: Can you post an image of the loss curves and probably the output of the confusion matrix?

Comment: I've added the graphs.

Comment: If you have good test accuracy when the model is on your PC, but bad accuracy when it is in the app, I guess the issue must be the transfer of the model. I would suggest that you provide a saved model, some code to load it up and run an example that it gets right, and your steps to make an android friendly model that gets this example wrong. If it looks like a bug you can also file a github issue with this reproduction instructions.

Comment: I've added the code I used to export the model and the code I used to implement the model on the Android App.

Comment: Thanks for posting the extra code. I couldn't spot any issues. My only suggestion is to replace your model with something completely trivial that you can verify on paper. Go through the steps of saving it and using in AndroidApp. Hopefully, you can narrow down the issue. If it looks like a bug at that point, file a bug report.